# Access management for AWS-based client-side SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I'm working on client-side SDK for my product (based on AWS). Workflow is as follows:

1. User of SDK **somehow** uploads data to **some** S3 bucket
2. User **somehow** saves command on **some** queue in SQS
3. One of the worker on EC2 polls the queue, executes operation and sends notification via SNS. This point seems to be clear.

As you might have noticed, there are quite **some** unclear points about access management here. Is there any common practice to provide access to AWS services (S3 and SQS in this case) for 3rd-party users of such SDK?

Options which I see at the moment:

- We create IAM-user for users of the SDK which have access to some S3 resources and write permission for SQS.
- We create additional server/layer between AWS and SDK which is writing messages to SQS instead of users as well as provides one-time short-living link for SDK to write data directly to S3.

First one seems to be OK, however I'm hesitant that I'm missing some obvious issues here. Second one seems to have a problem with scalability - if this layer will be down, whole system won't work.

P.S.

I tried my best to explain the situation, however I'm afraid that question might still lack some context. If you want more clarification - don't hesitate to write a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look closely at [Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) in order to limit customer access to only what they need, when they need it.

Keep in mind with any solution to this kind of problem, it depends on your scale, your customers, and what you are ok exposing to your customers.

With your first option, letting the customer directly use IAM or temporary credentials exposes knowledge to them that AWS is under the hood (since they can easily see requests leaving their system). It has the potential for them to make their own AWS requests using those credentials, beyond what your code can validate & control.

Your second option is better since it addresses this - by making your server the only point-of-contact for AWS, allowing you to perform input validation / etc before sending customer provided data to AWS.  It also lets you replace the implementation easily without affecting customers. On availablily/scalability concerns, that's what EC2 (and similar services) are for.

Again, all of this depends on your scale and your customers. For a toy application where you have a very small set of customers, simpler may be better for the purposes of getting something working sooner (rather than building & paying for a whole lot of infrastructure for something that may not be used).